# Mikrotik limit Socks server access from LAN

Tags: mikrotik, socks

I have a Mikrotik RB750 router that Socks server is configured on it. It has a interface in my LAN and another one in WAN with public IP address. I want to limit access to it from LAN. It seems that some people has found it and using it form WAN!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open `WinBox` . Go to **IP > Socks > Access** . The Socks Access window is similar to filter rule window. Default action in Socks Access is `accept`. This means that if no rule get matched, socks server accept that connection.

Now add a rule with `accept` action your LAN IP addresses range as its `Src Address`. Then add a rule with `deny` action. Left other field unchanged. This rule guaranty denying of any socks request other than your LAN IP addresses.

Comment: Is rule order important?

Comment: Yea. Rule matching is done from low index (below # field) to high index. If any rule is matched, it exit rule matching process.

Answer (score 2):

If socks server is running on port `1080` and your LAN IP address range is `192.168.10.0/24` use this in Mikrotik terminal:

```
/ip firewall filter add action=drop chain=input dst-port=1080 protocol=tcp src-address=!192.168.10.0/24
```

This command filters traffic by Mikrotik firewall.